# Can anyone reproduce the error I get in Excel when rounding up by ten?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to round up the minutes of my worktime in ten-steps (e.g 12 -> 20) in MS Excel.

I know the formula for doing so in Excel is (in German): =AUFRUNDEN(NUMBER;-1)
But problematically Excel sometimes does 10 -> 10 and othertimes 10 -> 20.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure both `10` in your image are exactly value 10? Because your function rounds up, so even if the value is `10,0000000001` it will be rounded up to 20. Could be that? Remember, is not the same what we see (format) and what the value is (the real value stored in cell). So if you have applied any format, it could be that

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I only enter whole numbers.

Comment: Those `10` are not formulas where you calculate the difference between the times in the first 2 columns? Do you type them manually?

Comment: The time difference (second right column) is getting calculated.

Comment: Could you upload a sample file somewhere so we can check the file and make some tests? I was not able to reproduce the error on my own

Comment: floating point error, may be `RoundUp(Round(x, 0), -1)` would solve this. 1st rounding is to correct the floating error, 2nd rounding is the wanted round to ten.

Comment: Under the following link you can load a test file where this behaviour gets demonstrated: https://www.kaffeemaier.de/sa4zie5boos4aitahph4/Excel_test_file.xls

Comment: @Rosetta your tip gave me the correct result. I have done =AUFRUNDEN(RUNDEN(G64;0);-1). But at the same time Excel tells me that the formula is invalid.

Comment: I don't even think this is per se a floating point error. For example row 64 on your sample data with 13 decimals would come down to a number higher than precisely 10. Which would round up to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing file. I was able to give an answer because of it :)

Is not an error. That annoying `10` is really `10,0000000000001`. Yes, with 13 decimals, but you are using ROUNDUP so it gets rounded up to 20.

If I change format in that column to show a lot of decimals, you will get this:

[image]

So is not a whole number, and that tiny part (13 decimals!!!) makes Excel to round up to 20 instead of 10.

Easy way would be making sure the value stored in the cell is an integer, with a normal round. In column G your formula is:

`=IF(F2;(F2-E2)*1440;D2*60)`

Replace it with:

`=ROUND(IF(F2;(F2-E2)*1440;D2*60);0)`

And now it works as you want:

[image]

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: I highly appreciate your effort, thanks! But I still don't get why sometimes you have the 1 at the end and sometimes not.

Comment: @FloatingPointOperation That's because you are changing a time value to decimal value in your formula. Decimal value are in base 10, and times are not. But Excel calculates everything in decimal system. If you select that problematic cell, in the ribbon options, Tab Formulas, click on **Evaluate**. You will see how Excel changes `11:10` and `11:20` to decimal values, gets the difference, and then multiply by 1440, and the result is `10,0000000000001`. But the reason is that time is not in decimal system, and when converting times, annoying decimals appears...